# Tomcat Permgen not increased even if I put it in Java options

Tags: java, tomcat, heap-memory, permgen

I'm running Tomcat 7 as a windows service in a Windows Server 2008 Machine. I've got a `Java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space` so I'm trying to increase its PermGen memory heap. So I specify this line at the end of JVM options:

> -XX:PermSize=512m  -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

As specified in the picture below:

[image]

The server is properly launched, however I cannot get the permgen size increased. When I enter Tomcat's management GUI, I can see the memory near the limit (the line at the end, PS Perm Gen):

[image]

So the application gets stuck after a while. Why is not Tomcat changing this value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of my experience you are allowed to put only one option per line.

Comment: @XtremeBiker - Then you can share the answer here.

Comment: I am struggling with same [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39737294/permgenspace-outofmemoryerror-maxpermsize-showing-default-value-always-rather) eventhough it is one option per line.